# ARM shellcode using r0 without null characters

Tags: arm, shellcode

I’m trying to write some basic ARM shell code that loads up the r0 register with 0. I cannot use null characters. I can see that

```
subs r2, r2, r2
```

sets r2 to 0 without using any null bytes.

However, any attempts to move r2 to r0, results in shell code that uses null bytes. Any advice on what I could do?

Comment: Just a quick idea that i can't verify right now - can't you `push r2` and `pop r0` ? IIrc, the register sets to be pushed and popped are bitfields in these instructions. If this doesn't work, maybe something like `push r2,r3` then `pop r0,r3` works.

Comment: arm, thumb or thumb2 ? And which processor model are you targeting exactly ?

Comment: you can push/pop (str/ldr) as Guntram suggests, or you can store/load from memory (stm/ldm) by using non-zero offsets, but you can't move it directly.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm subs r2, r2, r2;push {r2, r3};pop {r0, r3}; seems to assemble to "\x02\x20\x52\xe0\x0c\x00\x2d\xe9\x09\x00\xbd\xe8" and is hence not usable. Same case with push r2; pop r0;

Comment: You're right, the 1st byte of the 2nd and 3rd instruction is a bit field for registers 0-7, the 2nd byte (which is zero) is r8-r15. So you can use `push {r2.r8}; pop{r0,r8}` which assembles to `02 20 52 e0 04 01 2d e9 01 01 bd e8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy/pasted from [the online disassembler](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/):

```
.data :00000000  e0522002 subs r2, r2, r2
.data :00000004  e92d0104 push {r2, r8}       
.data :00000008  e8bd0101 pop {r0, r8}
```

Or, in thumb mode (the push/pop instructions are actually the same, seemingly being byte-swapped due to endianness):

```
.data :00000000 1a92 subs r2, r2, r2
.data :00000002 0104e92d stmdb r13!, {r2, r8}
.data :00000006 0101e8bd ldmia.w r13!, {r0, r8}
```